# Logistic regression and dependent variables in R

Tags: r, logistic

I’m trying to do logistic regression,

I utilize the following command:

```
mylogit <- glm(Var0 ~Var1, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
```

And I obtain a p-value of `0.003`

After that I want to know the effect of `Var2` and `Var3` and I use the following command:

```
mylogit <- glm(Var0 ~Var1+Var2+Var3, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
```

obtaining a p-value of `0.993`

My problem is that `Var1` and `Var2` are dependent and for that reason I obtain such p value.
Is there any method to indicate that `Var1` and `Var2` are dependent or I have to remove `Var2`?

Comment: you can specify interactions with `*`

Comment: What do you mean by dependent? if Var1 and Var2 are significantly correlated (problem of multicolinearity), there is no easy way around...

Comment: I mean that Var1 and Var2 have almost the same values

Comment: p-value for what test?

Comment: Can you include the output of `summary(mylogit)` for both cases to your question.

Answer (score 1):

That is a Multicolinearity issue. You can check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity including the remedies section. You'll probably have to forget about one variable in the specification... knowing that you can't distinguish which of var1 and var2 does what (i.e. you must take into account that the estimate you get for var1 if you include var1 only may actually reflect the effect of var2 "in real life")

Answer (score 1):

There is no method that will give you a boolean value of either "Yes you should remove `Var2`!" or "No do not remove `Var2`!" However, you seem to have correctly noticed that two of your variables, `Var1` and `Var2`, are highly correlated and so you ought to remove one. The one you remove can be selected by your preferred model fit statistic, cross-validation, or simply the one you are more interested in.